# magento set subcategory as rootcategory

Tags: magento

I have 1 magento installation with 2 websites. i want to set a subcategory from website 1 as rootcategory of website 2.

and i don't know the id of the category, because this is local and has to work on production with other categories. So i can't set the id of the wanted category in code.
it must be adjustable in the backend.

in system->manage stores-> select a store
here you can set the rootcategory but there are no subcategories available.

is the only solution to build a module to select the id of the category?

Answer (score 2):

copy

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php

to

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php

update around line 414

```
    $this->addLevelFilter(1);
```

to

```
    $this->addLevelFilter(2);
```

What this will do is when you go into System -> Manage Stores and click on the Store Name. 
It lets you set the Root Category. This dropdown will now not only display the root categories but also the level 2 categories. It's perfectly fine to use a subcategory as the root category in a certain store.

This is really beneficial if you're running a corporate site and then a bunch of branded sub-sites but you don't want to manage a million different duplicate categories.

Comment: This sounds ideal for what I need, but in Magento 1.9 CE it causes the category to disappear from the top menu, and gives 500 internal server errors on any of the pages within the category.

Comment: This worked fantastic for me - THANK YOU!  I wish I could mark this solved.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what it is you're trying to do but not why. Are you trying to display specific categories for each Store View? You don't have to worry about Root Category to solve this.

I'll assume you're using a newer version of Magento Community Edition 1.5+.

- Leave the category for both Store Views set to the same Root Category
  (default is Default Category)
- Go to Catalog > Manage Categories.
- For each website you will need to enable/disable each subcategory to
  build a custom catalog from the Root Category.
- Above the category listings you can switch which Store View you need to customize. Leave this set as "All Store Views" and customize which subcategories you want or don't want for Website 1.
- To do this just click on the specific category > General Information tab and set the Is Active to Yes or No. Disabled categories will grey out.
- Once completed switch to the Store View of the other website "Website 2" and select a category that will be different than the default.
- Now, to the right of the various fields you will see a checkbox (checked by default) labeled Use Default Value.
- Uncheck the Use Default Value checkbox beside the Is Active field and toggle it to yes/no.
- Save Category.
- Now when you view each store you will see that the catalog is different.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: not really because in the menu of website 2, the menu is showing the name of the root-category but it must show only the name of the subcategory. i will test it next time if i can disable the name of the root-category with css.
it's a magento Enterprise edition.